# PHP email not displaying option errors

Tags: php, html-email

```
$subject = 'Test';
$body = '<html>
            <head>
                <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <a href="http://lancenewman.me">Test</a>
            </body>
        </html>';

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n';

$headers .= 'From: Lance <support@lancenewman.me>' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'To: User <email@me.com>' . '\r\n';

//echo $headers;

mail('myemail@me.com', $subject, $body, $headers)or die('error');
```

The email gets sent but the `to` and `from` headers aren't showing up correctly. Gmail says that the email is send to my email, but not my name (Lance) like it's supposed to. The same is true for the `from` header. Also, all of the html tags are showing up in the email.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try again but this time place `error_reporting(E_ALL);` above the code.

Comment: Generally when you see html tags showing up, that means they are either invalid tags, or improperly formatted - they're obviously not being read right. have you tried throwing the html through an xhtml checker too see if there's anything invalid?

Comment: Why are you setting to in header. When it's the first argument to mail function?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say, Joni

Comment: What does the `email` variable contains?

Comment: This is php mail function: mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] ). First parameter is $to and in your $header you have set "To: "  manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it has to do with `'\r\n'` being in single quotes instead of double quotes, like `"\r\n"`, so it's not being evaluated, just a String Literal.

Comment: Cannot believe that it was something so trivial